# Angular directive to replace character from user input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I want to trim characters from my user input. Something like I want to trim '%, *, ), ( '
If user give any of this character I want to show it on search box but In the js I want to set model value without these restricted characters.

Something like:

```
user input 'a&b'

I want to set this in my scope as 'ab'
```

This question([Angular.js - controller function to filter invalid chars from input does not delete chars until a valid char is entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932782/angular-js-controller-function-to-filter-invalid-chars-from-input-does-not-del)) almost answers do what I want without showing it on the user.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not trim, you have to replace

Comment: You could use a $watch within your directive that watches the ng-model value. When the value changes (user inputs character) it will run the watch callback, where you can have your replacement method defined.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<script>

var user_input = "%this (is) a string*";

var new_string = plainString(user_input)
alert(user_input); 

function plainString()
{
    var findIt = [ '%', '*', ')', '('];
    for(i=0; i<findIt.length; i++) {
        user_input = user_input.replace(findIt[i],'');  
    }
    return;
}

</script>
```

Or you can use

```
<script>

String.prototype.myReplace = function(find, replace) {
    var str = this;
    for (var i = 0; i < find.length; i++) {
        str = str.replace(find[i], replace);
    }
    return str;
};

var user_input = '%this (is) a string*';
var find = ["%", "(", ")", "*"];
user_input = user_input.myReplace(find, "");
alert(user_input);

</script>
```

Output:

```
this is a string
```

Comment: Yes I asked about "Angular directive"